# How to change location of visual studio project?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

So I have a project I've been working on Visual Studio. By default, all vs projects go to `C:/User/Name/Documents/VisualStudio....` and so on. So I want to upload this entire project to github, and push through git everytime theres changes. Is there any way to make git look at this folder for changes or is there any way I can change this projects location and move it inside my github folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just cut the project and move it to your desired repos folder. Then just open it from there..